# What could cause user_hash_password() to crash this severely?

Tags: users

After making some major, but seemingly unrelated, changes to my login module (changes related to updating an LDAP with data from Drupal users), one of my uses of user_hash_password() is failing so badly, that the website returns with:

> Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://mybusiness.net/content/mywebsite?destination=node/1. It
>   may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
>   HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

No other errors. No hint as to what I'm looking for. I just figured out which line of code by chance, as it was originally part of the construction of an array.

The immediately relevant code I'm using (after deconstructing it) is:

```
terralog('Test step 18');
terralog('Pass '.$pass);
$passHash = user_hash_password($pass);
terralog('Test step 18.5');
terralog('hash '.$passHash);
```

It only prints the first two logs, so I can see that there is no other line of code that could be killing it. $pass proves to be the password in plain text, just as I expected. It is set once from the login form, and never modified again (unless ldap_bind() modifies it, but I can see that it does not). Something hidden must be affecting it, because I can't see anything besides $pass interacting with it on the surface. This function is one of the API functions (7 onwards), and a fairly simple one. What could possibly cause it to fail so badly?

Comment: Well, it's not a real answer, but I've realised that, if you're adding or modifying a user with user_save(), you don't need to call user_hash_password() at all, because it's handled by user_save(). Thus circumventing the problem, rather than solving it.